# Interpolation function precision in multi dimentional case

Tags: interpolation, arbitrary-precision

I have this interpolation example

```
zzz = Interpolation[{
    {{1}, 2`100*Pi},
    {{2}, 3`100*Pi},
    {{3}, 4`100*Pi}
    }, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
zzz[2]
zzz[2.5]
zzz[2.5`100]
```

and I am getting these resilts

```
9.424777960769379715387930149838508652591508198125317462924833776923449218858626995884104476026351204

10.9956

10.99557428756427633461925184147826009469009289781287037341230607307735742200173149519812188869740974
```

first number as expected with 100 digits, second with only 4 digits, but if I add `100 to the argument I can get it with 100 digits as well.

Now I use multidimensional example

```
testData = {
   {{-2.*10^-6, 0, -18}, -1.00853429340956742965680093076966025423734590973983188199800080460508043197286933569747093680631648*10^6},
   {{-2.*10^-6, 0, -17}, 
    952504.61044236930112440429386078472672512393090882097358420180063200222870428099604804394164585046},
   {{-2.*10^-6, 1, -18}, -1.008544941816832295575440188033483155333800668013690157106923425838109768669333223372232072904210136*10^6},
   {{-2.*10^-6, 1, -17}, -952514.6672734985329986920711230513627204920640531655413765067694156739368659196153982113188871999717},

   {{-1.78947*10^-6, 0, -18}, -1.00854109353837536345550608172429712197251598047769246281925070613484574642246277456744911673832572*10^6},
   {{-1.78947*10^-6, 0, -17}, -952511.41057117723492310944481542159446029400164668155440545170216176754315387443491802212157785970},

   {{-1.78947*10^-6, 1, -18}, -1.008551741385092646935524440345434727928230066236270646432464156954808417875408736480254883876917917*10^6},
   {{-1.78947*10^-6, 1, -17}, -952521.4668417583449142805833940440259658101867440498419481296004930320450422321944211465035742782570}
   };
ff[x1_, x2_, x3_] = Interpolation[testData, InterpolationOrder -> 1][x1, x2, x3]
```

and for this example, I cannot get the results with 100 digits, even if I use exact existing values

```
ff[-2.0`100*10`100^-6, 0.0`100, -18.0`100]
ff[-2.0`100*10`100^-6, 1.0`100, -18.0`100]

Out[350]= -1.00853*10^6
Out[351]= -1.00854*10^6
```

How to force interpolation to use required precision? There is no WorkingPrecision argument for interpolation.

UPDATE 1

even if I put `100 everywhere like this, it is still the same result

```
testData = {
   {{-2`100*10^-6, 0.0`100, -18`100}, -1.00853429340956742965680093076966025423734590973983188199800080460508043197286933569747093680631648`100*10^6},
   {{-2`100*10^-6, 0.0`100, -17`100}, 952504.61044236930112440429386078472672512393090882097358420180063200222870428099604804394164585046`100},

   {{-2`100*10^-6, 1`100, -18`100}, -1.008544941816832295575440188033483155333800668013690157106923425838109768669333223372232072904210136`100*10^6},
   {{-2`100*10^-6, 1`100, -17`100}, -952514.6672734985329986920711230513627204920640531655413765067694156739368659196153982113188871999717`100},

   {{-1.78947`100*10^-6, 0.0`100, -18`100}, -1.00854109353837536345550608172429712197251598047769246281925070613484574642246277456744911673832572`100*10^6},
   {{-1.78947`100*10^-6, 0.`100, -17`100}, -952511.41057117723492310944481542159446029400164668155440545170216176754315387443491802212157785970`100},

   {{-1.78947`100*10^-6, 1`100, -18`100}, -1.008551741385092646935524440345434727928230066236270646432464156954808417875408736480254883876917917`100*10^6},
   {{-1.78947`100*10^-6, 1`100, -17`100}, -952521.4668417583449142805833940440259658101867440498419481296004930320450422321944211465035742782570`100}
};
ff[x1_, x2_, x3_] = 
 Interpolation[testData, InterpolationOrder -> 1][x1, x2, x3]
```

Comment: You have machine precision numbers in data. I would expect the output to always be machine precision.

Comment: I thought if I have a number like this -1.0085342934095674296568009307696602542373459097398318819980008 (with 100 digits after dot) it is not machine precision anymore.

Comment: I put `100 explicitly everywhere (in UPDATE 1) and the result is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evaluate `` 0.0`100 `` and you'll get a machine precision zero.  Use the exact `0` instead:

```
fff = Interpolation[testData /. x_ /; x == 0 -> 0, InterpolationOrder -> 1];

fff[-2.`100.*^-6, 0, -18.`100.]
(*
-1.0085342934095674296568009307696602542373459097398318819980008046050\
804319728693356974709368063165*10^6
*)
```

Comment: It works, thank you, but looks like a bug. how can I remember all these tricks :) Also if I do like this

`ff[-2.0\`100*10\`100^-6, 0, -18.0]`

it does not work, but if I do like that
`ff[-2.0\`100*10\`100^-6, 0, -18.0\`100]`

it works. What is the difference between 0 and -18.0? And what will happen, if I want to make a graph (Plot) of this function? Will it be full precision or again only machine precision?

Comment: @Zlelik Don't you mean the difference between the machine precision `-18.0` and the 100-digit precision ``-18.0`100``?  Somewhere in the docs I think there's an explanation that zero cannot have a precision other than `Infinity` (i.e. exact) or `MachinePrecision`; it can have an `Accuracy`, though.  The reason is that the precision of `x` is defined to be the uncertainty divided by `x`, and you cannot divide by `x`.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. But why result is different for `ff[-2.0\`100*10\`100^-6, 0, -18.0]` and `ff[-2.0\`100*10\`100^-6, 0, -18.0\`100]`?

Comment: @Zlelik According to the tutorial [Machine-Precision Numbers](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MachinePrecisionNumbers.html), when you give machine-precision input to most expressions, including `InterpolatingFunction`, you get machine-precision output, no matter the precision of other parts of the expression.

Comment: I see. thank you for the link. What can I do to force Plot function to use full precision, but not machine precision? if I just do `Plot[ff[-2.0\`100*10\`100^-6, 0, x], {x,-18,18}]` it will use machine precision and I will get wrong graph. Will it work properly if I do like this `Plot[ff[-2.0\`100*10\`100^-6, 0, x], {x,-18\`100,18\`100}]`?

Comment: @Zlelik Try the option `WorkingPrecision -> 100` in `Plot`.  After computing the function values at high precision, `Plot` will still convert the coordinates to machine precision (for the GPU). So for plotting a simple interpolating function (as opposed to a more complex expression built up from one), I'm not sure `WorkingPrecision` will make a difference.